# Get returned data from async function

Tags: javascript

With the following async function I get data from a firebase firestore instance:

```
export async function getSomething(db, id) {
  db.collection('someting').doc(id).get().then((doc) => {
    if (doc.exists) {
      return doc.data();
    }
    throw new Error('No such document!');
  }).catch((error) => {
    throw new Error('err', error);
  });
}
```

I called this function like:

```
getSomething(db, this.id).then((data) => {
  console.log(data); // data is empty here
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

The issue is, that on the `data` from the `then` function is empty.
How can I get the data from the `getSomething` function? Is returning the data not enough?

Comment: 1) There's no reason for your function to be `async` since you're not using `await`. 2) `return db.collection...`

Comment: Why are you using an async function will there is no use of `await` operator?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get a value back from a function, then you need to return something from it.

You have a number of return statements, but they are all inside callbacks.

You need one for getSomething itself.

```
return db.collection('someting').doc(id).get().then((doc) => {
```